# How can I create a list of rows that have one of a list of properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a difficult LINQ query that I would like to do. Here's what I have:

List of `IJapaneseDictionaryEntry` objects which are described below.  Inside this are `IKanji` objects.

```
public interface IJapaneseDictionaryEntry
{
    int Sequence { get; }
    IEnumerable<IKanji> Kanjis { get; }
    IEnumerable<IReading> Readings { get; }
    IEnumerable<ISense> Senses { get; }
}
```

Where each object contains a list of `IKanji` objects

```
public interface IKanji
{
    string Text { get; }
    IEnumerable<KanjiInformation> Informations { get; }
    IEnumerable<Priority> Priorities { get; }
}
```

I am using this query:

```
var b = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)
         .Where(x => x.Priorities.Any())
         .Select(x => new { x.Text, x.Priorities });
```

but instead of .Any() I would like to select those rows that contain a property of Frequency1 or Frequency2 or Frequency3 all the way up to Frequency24

Is there some way I can do this and replace the .Any with a construct that will mean Any of Frequency1,  Frequency2,  Frequency3 ... Frequency24

I added an image to show the priority class. The code values go from nf1 to nf24

[image]

[image]

For reference, here's the priority class with a few sample frequencies:

```
namespace Wacton.Desu
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;

    using Wacton.Tovarisch.Enum;

    public class Priority : Enumeration
    {
        public static readonly Priority Newspaper1 = new Priority("Newspaper1", "news1");
        public static readonly Priority Newspaper2 = new Priority("Newspaper2", "news2");
        public static readonly Priority Frequency1 = new Priority("Frequency1", "nf01");
        public static readonly Priority Frequency2 = new Priority("Frequency2", "nf02");
        public static readonly Priority Frequency3 = new Priority("Frequency3", "nf03");
        public static readonly Priority Frequency4 = new Priority("Frequency4", "nf04");
        public static readonly Priority Frequency5 = new Priority("Frequency5", "nf05");

        public string Code { get; }

        private static int counter;
        public Priority(string displayName, string code)
            : base(counter++, displayName)
        {
            this.Code = code;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the solution 明白? :) Sorry - I'll show myself out.

Comment: Can you show the definition for `Priority` and an example of `Frequency10`?

Comment: Can you show how the `Priority` class is defined?

Comment: I don't suppose these Frequency1..24 types are all subclasses of a parent Frequency class / implement an IFrequency ?

Comment: I will add an image for priority

Comment: No, please add the code - not an image of it.

Comment: Even giving us a wider screenshot of the locals window (so the type column was visible) would be more helpful

Comment: @CaiusJard - I hope that the 2nd image I gave you is a help.  I don't have access to the Frequency class. The data I have has been created from a SQL database which was then output to XAML and I extracted the data from the XAML.  Wish I could have access to the source database but all I have access to is the XAML.

Comment: @John - I added the class which is used when generating the Priority details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming, from the extra fragments posted, that every Priority has a Code, and every Frequency priority has a Code like "nf...", so you can put a Boolean test in your Any:

```
...Priorities.Any(pri => pri.Code.StartsWith("nf"))
```

If there are Frequencys higher than 24 and you want to exclude them you might need to get more cute with your Boolean test. It might be enough to:

```
...Priorities.Any(pri => pri.Code.StartsWith("nf") && (pri.Code.Length == 3 || pri.Code <= "nf24"))
```

It largely depends on how this library is structured, how it will change over time; design decisions for you to make rather than us- but this should give you some ideas

Comment: Works very well.  Thanks